# Finding the shortest path in non-complete node-weighted graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Normally, Simulated Annealing (SA) is used in TSP problem to find the near-to-optimal solution, and the graph structure in TSP is a **complete graph**. Therefore, I want to know whether or not I can use SA for finding the shortest path/optimal solution in a **non-complete(connected undirected) weighted graph** in the 2 dimentional Euclidean space.

If I cannot use SA in this case, could you recommend me a good algorithm for this?
*** Note: the weight here is referred to the weight on each node, not edge weight.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Simulated Annealing is just an estimation technique, you can use it to solve pretty much any problem.  However there's no guarantee the solutions it finds will be any good...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanks for your quick comment. So, could you please recommend me a good shortest path algorithm for this problem?

Comment: You can use SA.  Or there are plenty of approximation algorithms for it, search around.  "Non-complete weighted graph" is the usual setup for the problem.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thank you so much for your response and advice. I have one more  question. Can i use k-means to cluster a non-complete graph like in my case? Because mostly, i only see many people applied it in a complete graph.

Comment: "Shortest path" is something very different from "shortest TSP tour". You mean the latter, right?

Comment: @adrianN Thank you for your question. I meant "shortest path" not "shortest TSP tour" because my problem is not TSP. It is just similar to TSP that we have to find the shortest path of all routes, and my graph structure is a connected undirected graph, not a complete graph.

Comment: So do you want to find the shortest path that visits every node exactly once or something different?

Comment: @adrianN Not exactly once because each node has different frequency of visit (node-weighted), which means some nodes are visited once and some other are visited more than once. So, I want to find the shortest path that visits every node by taking into account their frequency of visit.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what problem you're trying to solve? What is the input? What are you trying to compute? Please give a precise definition and, if it would help, an example.